# Oracle sql developer export: encoding box is giving any option

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: Encoding Box: keeps loading.]

whenever I try to export the results into txt file or any type of files. it create only empty file with fetching the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you click on that Encoding dropdown?

Comment: I've changed *'ecoding'* to *'encoding'* as a start, but I still don't understand the question. Did you mean it's *not* giving any option? Did you mean it creates a file *without* fetching the data?